# After publishing website (WebPublish) login database not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been doing a website with VS13 Express and MVC 5. I'm using ExternalLogin using owin. The project uses a local db generated axiomatically.
In local it works perfectly.
When deploying the website using WebDeploy, deploys the [db].mdf to the server, but when executing the login it's not able to found the database.

Here's my connectionString in web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WhyIsItBad2-20131015123340.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WhyIsItBad2-20131015123340;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And here's the Settings for WebDeploy

```
Configuration: Release
File Publish Options: Remove additional files at destination

Databases:
----------
ApplicationDbContext(DefaultConnection)
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\lissie\Desktop\WhyIsItBad2\WhyIsItBad2\App_Data\aspnet-WhyIsItBad2-20131015123340.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
Use this connection string at runtime(update destination web.config)
Execute Code First Migrations (run on application start)
```

As you can see I have migration activated.
At the Preview step of WebDeploy the database appears in the Databases sections. And the deploy doesn't generate any errors.

But when trying the login in the website I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

    The system cannot find the file specified

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Source Error: 

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

    [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

    [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296071
       System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
       System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308555
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +920
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +434
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +558
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +67
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +83
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
       System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<UsingConnection>b__2d() +73
       System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
       System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
       System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +77
       System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +229
       System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +376
       System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +200
       System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +85

    [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
        System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +269
        System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +33

    [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.]
       System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +193
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k) +31
       System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +180
       System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +56
       System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +43
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +62
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +575
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
       System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserIdAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +728
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<GetUserIdForLoginAsync>d__3.MoveNext() +184
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<SignInExternalIdentityAsync>d__1e.MoveNext() +245
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
       Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<SignInExternalIdentityAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +181
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
       WhyIsItBad2.Controllers.<ExternalLoginCallback>d__27.MoveNext() +460
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
       lambda_method(Closure , Task ) +23
       System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +33
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass34.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__33(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +16
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9628700
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

For what I understand the problem is that the application can't find the database.
I haven't found in google anything to help me solution this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WhyIsItBad2-20131015123340;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried removing ;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WhyIsItBad2-20131015123340.mdf from the connection string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try changing "(LocalDb)\v11.0" to "." (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have SQL Server installed locally and that the service is running.